# Parsing XML File with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am having an issue parsing an XML file.  I have other PHP scripts that do this but for some reason this one just won't work.

```
XML Example:
<Data>
<Email>
      <Subject>Email</Subject>
      <Sender>Sender</Sender>
      <Recipients>'recipient1', recipient2</Recipients>
      <Date>2014-02-24T22:37:16Z</Date>
      <Size>16 KB</Size>
      <Url>URL</Url>
   </Email>
</Data>
```

and

```
PHP Example:
<?php
$file="data.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die ('Cant Load XML');
echo "
<table>
<tr>
<th>Subject</th>
<th>Sender</th>
<th>Recipients</th>
<th>Date/Time</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Link</th>
</tr>
";
foreach($xml->Data as $data){
foreach($data->children() as $he => $email){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>{$email->Subject}</td>";
echo "<td>{$email->Sender}</td>";
echo "<td>{$email->Recipients}</td>";
echo "<td>{$email->Date}</td>";
echo "<td>{$email->Size}</td>";
echo "<td><a href={$email->URL}>Link</a></td>";
echo "<br />";
echo "</tr>";
}}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

I get the header rows but after that it seems like nothing processes.  I do not get an error so it seems to be loading the XML.  Not sure why this one is not working but similar scripts I have do.  Maybe a fresh pair of eyes would help?

Comment: Did you try adding `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the top?

Comment: "This one wont work" isn't helpful. What exactly isn't working? Are you getting any error messages? What do you expect to happen and what is happening? We can't help you unless you tell us what is wrong.

Comment: Does `var_dump($data->Email);` return anything?

Comment: Try example 1 in this link: http://us1.php.net/simplexml_load_file and see what happens

Comment: `var_dump($xml)` would should you what you actually got.

Comment: Is `Data` the root node? If so, you need to remove the inner loop and just do `foreach($xml->Email as $email)`

Comment: I tried var_dump($xml) and got back what I expected.

Comment: ... which is? a node containing `<Email> ... </Email>` ? because if that is the case and Email is a direct child of Data, you can just call `$data->Email`

Comment: foreach($xml->Email as $email)  seems to have got it.  I had thought I tried that -_-  Thank you so much for your help everyone!

Comment: @NDunn: Common beginner mistake, the XML root element (here: `<Data>`) is already represented by `$xml`. See as well http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)